# Red artifact on visualizing rtsp stream via gstreamer and qt5

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5, gstreamer

I've written a c++ program that receives a RTSP stream via gstreamer and displays this video via Qt5 in a QWidget. As the gstreamer videosink, I use a Widgetqt5glvideosink.

The problem is when I look at the received stream it has too much red-value in it. This only occurs when the vertical resolution exceeds +-576 pixels. (lower resolutions have no issue)
When I use cpu rendering (Widgetqt5videosink) instead of openGL rendering i get a correct image.
When I view the stream via gstreamer command line or via VLC it is also correct.

So it likes to be an issue when using an openGL rendered QWidget.

Is this an driver issue or something else?

Info:
Tested on Ubuntu16.04 and 17.04 for the viewer application.

Links:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/qtvideosink_overview.html

Comment: 576 can somehow be connected with [576i TV standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/576i) also known as PAL/SECAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by patching two files in the source code of qt-gstreamer.
There were two wrong color matrices of the colorimetry BT709.
[Patch to fix red artifact in Widgetqt5glvideosink](https://bug781816.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=350558)